# Python, strange loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The program has to detect anagrams of a word given with a list of candidates.I managed to get it right except for a something strange with the last loop: it's supposed to drop words with same letters with different number of occurrence , which seems to work fine , EXCEPT if that word has similar consecutive letters, and i cant tell why.

```
def detect_anagrams(word,candidates):

    anagrams = []
    count = True
    for element in candidates:

        if set(element.lower()) == set(word.lower()):
            if element.lower() == word.lower():
                pass
            else:
                for char in element:
                    if element.count(char) == word.count(char):
                        count = True
                    else:
                        count = False
                if count == True:
                    anagrams.append(element)

    return anagrams

    pass
```

Comment: Please show an example input/output that shows the problem, and show what you expect it to output. And what's the point of the `pass` at the bottom?

Comment: @Carcigenicate input: a word and a list of candidates to check if they are anagrams : detect_anagrams(galea,['eagle']) it should return a list of the matching anagrams of the given word (none in this case, so output: [ ] ) but in case the word is 'good' and the list contains 'dog' and 'goode' for example, 'dog' is not discarded . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you failed to post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and your description isn't quite clear, I'm not sure how your program is *supposed* to work.  However, I think I can spot the logic problem.

```
            for char in element:
                if element.count(char) == word.count(char):
                    count = True
                else:
                    count = False
            if count == True:
                anagrams.append(element)
```

You iterate through all the chars in `element`, checking each pair of counts.  However, note that you reassign the value of `count` each time through the loop.  When you get to `if count == True`, the only information you have from the loop is `count` for the *last* char in `element`; all of the other info is lost.  I think you want to know if *any* count matches, rather than only the last one.  This would look like

```
            count = True
            for char in element:
                if element.count(char) != word.count(char):
                    count = False

            if count == True:
                anagrams.append(element)
```

Does that work for you?

Note: I have not cleaned up your use of Boolean expressions.  Try this:

```
            count = True
            for char in element:
                count = count and element.count(char) == word.count(char):

            if count:
                anagrams.append(element)
```

... or simply use the `any` and `all` operators:

```
            if all [element.count(char) == word.count(char)
                    for char in element] :
                anagrams.append(element)
```

Comment: I don't believe you can use `any` to qualify an anagram.  You can use `all` to qualify one or, better yet, `not any` to disqualify one.  But saying that if the words have the same number of *any* character, it's anagram is incorrect.  It has to be the same number of *all* characters.  Or, better yet, it's not an anagram if it does not have the same number of *any* character.

Comment: I see OPs comment now ... yes, my logic is backward.  Thanks; I'll fix it.

Comment: @mufasa, these loops work but are bad algorithms.  The reason is that once a character fails the count test, there's no reason to test the remaining characters.  Yet all these loops wait until *all* the characters have been counted to do the test and so are inefficient.  As soon as the count comparison  fails, the logic should break out of the loop and move onto the next candidate.

Answer (score 0):

This logic is wrong:

```
if element.count(char) == word.count(char):
    count = True
else:
    count = False
```

If one letter count doesn't match, you allow the next letter to reset `count` to `True` -- once a letter fails to match, break out of the loop, game over.  You also fail to properly control case in this part of the code even though you did so earlier.  Here's a rework of your code:

```
def detect_anagrams(word, candidates):

    word_lower = word.lower()
    word_set = set(word_lower)

    anagrams = []

    for candidate in candidates:

        candidate_lower = candidate.lower()

        if set(candidate_lower) == word_set:
            if candidate_lower != word_lower:
                for character in candidate_lower:
                    if candidate_lower.count(character) != word_lower.count(character):
                        break
                else:  # no break
                    anagrams.append(candidate)

    return anagrams
```

Notice that we only have to lower case and make a set of `word` once, not in every loop iteration.  Also note I'm using an uncommon `else` on a `for` (not on the `if`) which fires if the loop exited normally, not via the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but this part is definitely not correct:

```
           for char in element:
                if element.count(char) == word.count(char):
                    count = True
                else:
                    count = False
```

as it finishes with the value of the `count` variable depending only on the *last* `char` in `element` (as its value is in the `for` loop repeatedly rewritten)

Answer (score 0):

Give direct respond to your given example

```
detect_anagrams("good",["dog","goode"])
```

`dog` is not dropped because the flag `count` gets set back to `true`.
When comparing the char `o` of `dog` as `element.count(char)` with char `o` in the word `good` word.count(char) you are doing a comparison of 1 == 2 ? which is not true so the `count` flag get set to `false`

But then since there is no `BREAK`

the next character  `g` in `dog` gets compare with char `g` in the word `good` you are doing a comparison of 1 == 1? which is true. So your program set the flag `count` back to `true`

What your code doing is essentially comparing the if the last character in `word` appears an exact number of times in `element` in your candidates. that means your program would interpret 'notoriousBIG' is an anagram of 'watermelon' since n appears once in both words.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that a candidate word is invalid if it has more of one letter than the target word, you can use the built-in `any` to check for any violation:

```
with open('corncob_lowercase.txt') as f:
    candidates = f.read().splitlines()

def detect_anagrams(word,candidates):
    anagrams = []
    for element in candidates:
        if element == word:
            continue
        if not any(element.count(char) > word.count(char) for char in element):
            anagrams.append(element)
    return anagrams

print(detect_anagrams('good',candidates))
```

> ['do', 'dog', 'go', 'god', 'goo']

Word list link: http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt

Comment: I think you're misreading his example.  When the OP says, "'dog' is not discarded", I believe he means, "'dog' is not discarded, but it should have been".  Since we're looking for anagrams, `element.count(char) > word.count(char)` probably should be `element.count(char) != word.count(char)`.  I like the way you set up your loop, it gives the appearance of counting all the characters, then testing, but its generator nature, and the way `any` consumes it, make it nicely stop on the first mismatch.